# Cannot find an initializer for type CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: json, swift

I have this line:

```
marker.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
```

lat and lng are both from a JSON array and this is the error that I am getting:

```
Cannot find an initializer for type CLLocationCoordinate2D that accepts an argument list of type (latitude: JSON, longtitude: JSON)
```

I have tried other types like `lng.int` but it doesn't work either. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I had to use `doubleValue` as type. So it works when I use `lat.doubleValue` for example.